# Emulator startup issue

Tags: android-emulator, kernel, multi-touch

I am trying to run a standard AVD (ARM, empty layout, other settings as proposed by Android Studio) on the emulator. Enabled `-verbose`, `-debug all` and `-show-kernel` modes.

The emulator boots, but ends up in complaining that it cannot connect to a certain socket (127.0.0.1:1970). I tried to open a TCP socket at this port, and got a message from SDKCtl multi-touch - it is trying to establish an handshake.

Does anybody know a workaround, or may at least explain what SDKCtl exactly is, and what it is trying to connect to?

I am on a Mac with El Capitan.

UPDATE

I found a workaround. Just use, when starting the emulator, the option:

```
-screen no-touch
```

At this point Android boots (very slowly), the device screen is not empty anymore, but a "process system isn't responding" message appears, and the system stays there.

SECOND UPDATE

In the log from the emulator, I noticed this error:

```
goldfish_fb 9010000.goldfish_fb: coherent DMA mask 0xffffffff is smaller than system GFP_DMA mask 0xffffffffffffffff
```

THIRD UPDATE

If one does not issue the `-screen no-touch` option, and waits *a lot*, in the end the virtual device boots, with the "process system isn't responding" message. At this point one may click on "wait" on the device message. And then the device seems to work. But the errors in the log are still there.